# Inverse Laplace Transform, I need help

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the ILT of $H(s)=\frac{7(3s+1)}{(s-3)(s^2+10s-13)}$

Also, if you kindly want to help with this another inverse transform, I'd really appreciate it: $H(s)=\frac{6(s+2)}{s^3(s-5)}$

Thanks!

Comment: Try partial fractions...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

For the first:
$H(s) =  \frac{35}{13  ( s-3\ ) }-\frac{35 s+182}{13 ( {s}^{2}+10 s-13 ) }$, and you can write $\frac{35 s+182}{13 ( {s}^{2}+10 s-13 ) } = \frac{35 ( s+5 ) +7}{13 { ( s+5 ) }^{2}-494} $.

If you let $\hat{h}_3(s) = {35 \over 13} {s \over x^2-38}$, and 
$\hat{h}_4(s) = {7 \over 13} {1 \over x^2-38}$, then the corresponding time functions are
$h_3(t) = {35 \over 13} \cosh(\sqrt{38}t)$, $h_4(t) = {35 \over 13} {1 \over \sqrt{38}} \sinh(\sqrt{38}t)$ (I am assuming $t>0$ here).

Note that the last term in $H(s)$ can be written as $-(\hat{h}_3(s+5)+\hat{h}_4(s+5))$, hence the corresponding time function is $-e^{-5t} (h_3(t)+h_4(t))$.

For the second: $H(s) = \frac{42}{125 ( s-5 ) } -\frac{42}{125 s}-\frac{42}{25 {s}^{2}}-\frac{12}{5 {s}^{3}} $.

Comment: That's for the first or the second one? Thank you very much1

Comment: Yes. I have edited the answer slightly.

Comment: I really really appreciate it! I'd try to investigate the next steps, the thing is that I just know how to do simple inverse transforms, but these ones are really difficult to me. Thanks!

Comment: Use tables. Look at multiplication by an exponential and power of $t$ in the time domain and the Laplace transform of $\sinh$. There is some pattern recognition involved.

Comment: Do you mean that just by those hints you gave me, I can use the tables to get h(t)? I have seen some close examples and they seem to be longer. Sorry for my ignorance, I just have 2 days studying laplace transforms and this homework is for today.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I can see some of those related on the table, but I still have doubts :/ I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Read my comments. For example, with ${\cal L} (t \mapsto e^{5t}) (s) = {1 \over s-5}$, so you can figure out the first terms of the above. Look at $\sinh$, powers of $t$ and multiplication by exponentials.

Comment: but what do I do with the fractions 42/125, 42/25 and 12/5? Do I put them on the left of the h(t) based of the table?

Comment: The Laplace transform is linear. If $c$ is a constant, then ${\cal L} (cf) = c {\cal L} (f)$.

Comment: Then it will be something like: 42/125e^(5t) - 42/125 - 42/25 t^(2) - 12/5t^(3)  Is this correct?

Comment: Close. The last two powers of $t$ should be $t,t^2$. The constant on the last term should be ${6 \over 5}$.

Comment: Thank you! just please throw me a last hint with the first one... I still don't know how to relate it with the table and choose the correct h(t).

Comment: Multiplying a function in the time domain by $e^{-5t}$ will result in the Laplace transform variable $s$ of the original function being replaced by $s+5$. So this reduces the last term to ${35 s+ 7 \over 13s^2-494}$. Split this into two terms and use the tables for $\sinh$ and $\cosh$.

Comment: The closest is e^(at)cos(wt)    w^(2) is 494? Edit: ok, let me try it.

Comment: Not $\cos$, you need hyperbolic functions since the constant in the denominator is negative.

Comment: 35s/13s^(2)-494 and 7/13s^(2)-494 = e^(-5t)(35cos(?t) + 7sen(?t)) I don't know what "w" is…  its sqr494, is it?

Comment: This is getting a little tedious and I need to sleep. Look for SINH/COSH not the trigonometric functions (this is my 4th time repeating this). The rest you need to work out.

Comment: I added some elaboration above, hope it helps.